# Inconsistent accessibility although class public

Tags: c#

I keep getting two errors of "Inconsistent accessibility" indicating that "... is less accessible than method ...".

I have searched for a solution to this problem, and every answer was, basically, "Make the class public."

I am therefore stuck, because the class is already public.

Here is where the errors occur:

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll")]
public static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

/// <summary>
/// Get the inner bounds of client window 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hWnd"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static RECT GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    RECT result;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, out result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Read the entire error message.  It's probably complaining about `RECT`.

Comment: You're right. I changed it to Rectangle, and it's okay now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I knew RECT should work. I realized what I was doing wrong.

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll")]
public static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

public static RECT GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    RECT result;
    GetClientRect1(hWnd, out result);
    RECT appRect = result;
    return result;
}
```

appRect should rightly be RECT rather than Rectangle, since they are of a different type. RECT works due to its structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything from the code in the question.  You mentioned `Rectangle` in your answer and a comment, but it's missing from the code?